# Quando converter um código 32-bit para 64-bit no iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, int, 64-bits, 32-bits

Sei que existem diversas informações a respeito da conversão de um código 32-bit para 64-bit no iOS. Porém, tenho ainda muitas dúvidas e acredito que sejam as mesmas de outras pessoas, principalmente na questão das variávies do tipo `int`. Por exemplo, como pude verificar, `int` é usado para 32-bit e `long` para 64-bit.
No entatnto, estou desenvolvendo um app que possui somente variáveis do tipo `int`, coloco a arquitetura para `Standard architectures (including 64-bit)` e executo no simulador. O app é executado de forma correta sem nenhum *warning* ou erro. Mesmo executado (aparentemente) de forma correta, eu tenho que alterar as variáveis para o tipo `long`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não. Talvez possa precisar mudar se algum `int` for usado como um ponteiro. Essencialmente o que muda de fato quando passa para 64 bits é o tamanho do ponteiro que em geral você não precisa se preocupar. A preocupação é necessária só quando tenta intercambiar tipos numéricos com ponteiros.

Comment: Ok. Como não usei estas variáveis como ponteiro, vou manter o código como está. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

A grande diferença entre arquiteturas 32 bits e 64 bits é quanto ao espaço de endereçamento que é muito maior em arquiteturas de 64 bits.

Portanto, a principal diferença em tipos de dados entre estas arquiteturas é em tipos que armazenam endereços de memória, ou seja, ponteiros.

Por exemplo, em uma arquitetura 32 bits, `sizeof(void*)` retorna 4 bytes, enquanto que em um arquitetura 64 bits o mesmo comando retorna 8 bytes. Esta diferença é necessária para que todo o espaço de endereçamento seja efetivamente endereçado.

Existem outras questões como `setjmp` e `longjmp`, mas estas estão mais associadas com as instruções (ISA).

Enfim, você deve alterar de `int` para `long` se você for usar valores que o `int` não comportam, Do contrário, não há com que se preocupar neste sentido.

Os `int`'s da vida só são problemáticos se você realiza *casts* entre ponteiros e inteiros. Algumas bibliotecas utilizam isso ao invés de utilizarem *opaque pointers*. Nestes casos, espera-se que a biblioteca tome os cuidados necessários para manter a consistência quando a biblioteca é compilada em 64 bits, e o programador deve fazer uso dos tipos de dados da biblioteca, tornando estas alterações transparentes.

Por fim, deve-se tomar cuidado quando se fixa o tamanho de estruturas que contém ponteiros. Por exemplo:

```
typedef struct {
    int *a;
} myStruct;
```

Se executarmos o comando `sizeof(myStruct)` nas duas arquiteturas, vamos obter tamanhos diferentes para a mesma estrutura.

Imagine o código:

```
myStruct p;
fread(&p, 4, 1, file);
```

*estou usando um exemplo absurdo mas que irá servir para explicar o ponto*

Em uma plataforma 64 bits, ele não daria o resultado esperado, uma vez que a estrutura `myStruct` possui tamanho 8 bytes, mas como o tamanho da estrutura foi fixado no comando `fread`, iremos ignorar 4 bytes do arquivo, que podem vir a causar resultados absurdos ou o *crash* da aplicação.

Para evitar isso é muito simples: basta utilizar `sizeof`:

```
myStruct p;
fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, file);
```

Comment: Obrigado. Resposta bastante esclarecedora.